# How to upload a entire structured folder to eXist-db database through RESTful

Tags: eclipse, upload, directory, exist-db

Could someone tell me that how to upload an entire structured folder to eXist-db database through RESTful?

Here is what I attempt to achieve: I have a folder which contains data file, and it has sub-folders which form the hierarchy of the root folder. Is it possible for me to upload the entire root folder of data to the local eXist-db database using RESTful, so I can access to the data files like this:

http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/basefolder/branch1/dev/documents/File.xml

in Eclipse.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write some script to do this. Two main options:

1) Write it client-side in the language of your choice, and have a script that loops through your files HTTP PUT'ing each of them to the database.

2) Write it server-side in XQuery. You then just Zip/Gz your directory structure and HTTP POST the zip file to your XQuery installed in eXist. Your XQuery should unpack the Zip and store each entry from the zip file into the database.

Comment: very informative answer, I was waiting for a reply like yours for days, thank you so much for helping me with this. Cheers.